# How does work LexicalEnvironment and VariableEnvironment?

Tags: javascript

In first example, I expected to see undefined instead 3. Why does console show 3 in first example?
Is it related with LexicalEnvironment and VariableEnvironment?

```
function test(num) {
  var num
  console.log(num) // 3
}
test(3)
```

and

```
function test(num) {
  var num = 5
  console.log(num) // 5
}
test(3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why does console show 3 in first example?

`num` is already declared in the environment, as parameter. Hence the `var num` statement is ignored.

The same happens in the second example. But here you have an assignment as well. Variable declarations with initial values are basically evaluated in two separate steps:

1. As part of setting up the new function lexical environment, all declared variables are collected. Because there is already a parameter with the same name, the variable declaration is ignored.
2. Then every statement of the function body is evaluated, and in that phase the assignment (`num = 5`) takes pace.

> Is it related with LexicalEnvironment and VariableEnvironment?

A LexicalEnvironment is a construct for associating identifier names with values, so yes, it's certainly related.

However, how a function body is evaluated is defined in [*FunctionDeclarationInstantiation*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation). Ignoring variable declarations which already exists as parameter names is defined in step 27.